# conda init powershell - no action taken - operation failed

Tags: powershell, anaconda, conda

In both cmd and powershell, when I input `conda init powershell`, it always failed as follows:

```
(ifcmapping) C:\Windows\system32>conda init powershell
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\condabin\rename_tmp.bat
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\condabin\conda_auto_activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\condabin\deactivate.bat
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\Scripts\activate
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\Scripts\deactivate
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\xontrib\conda.xsh
no change     C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
needs sudo    C:\Users\haoli\OneDrive\??\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
No action taken.
Operation failed.
```

I already run as Admin. How to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Is the `\??\ ` in the 3d line from the bottom a literal part of the output line, or the result of you redacting information?

Comment: It is a literal part @mklement0

Comment: That sounds like a problem, given that no literal path may contain `?` chars. From a PowerShell console, what does `$PROFILE` report?

Comment: I typed `notepad $PROFILE` in the PowerShell console but a message poped up saying that "the system cannot find the path specified" @mklement0

Comment: `$PROFILE` should contain the full path to your user- and PowerShell-host-specific profile file. Your symptom suggests that either that path is corrupted, or that the file doesn't exist yet. To rule out the latter, run `if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $PROFILE)) { New-Item -Force $PROFILE }`

Answer (score 0):

In here

> needs sudo    C:\Users\haoli\OneDrive??\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1

I  assume the ??\ are not English letters, you need to change it to English.

Check onedrive online, it is English on my local PC but not in English in the cloud. I changed the folder name to 'Documents'(where my PowerShell is at) in the cloud and synced the change to local. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows when you let OneDrive back up your Documents folder, the folder points to the Documents folder on the cloud, and the actual name of it depends on the language of your system, which I assume it is "文档" in your case.

I just disabled the Documents backup in OneDrive settings, and re-run `conda init`, which gave me the result

> modified      C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1

If you'd prefer not disabling the OneDrive backup, you can try Zixin's answer, I am just not sure if you should mess up with the default settings of the backup folder and if it will cause problem.